# How to open Dialer Activity from a webviewclient with clicked number?

Tags: android, android-webview, android-dialer

I am implementing a web view in my application. now when a user clicks on a phone number it shows **net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME**. But if i use chrome. it brings the dialer application with that phonenumber.

I need the exact same thing in my application. When a phone number is clicked within webview then the dialer needs to be opened with that phone number.

Here is my `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` Method for the webview. I can see there is answer [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9783576/how-to-open-dialer-activity-from-a-webviewclient) But i am pretty new to android and java and i couldn't make this thing work till now.

```
 public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
        progressBar.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
   }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This must be working. we need to override the `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` method of the webview class. and check if the url contains the `tel:xxxx` Then create an intent for the dialer and invoke the dialer. and we can call any application we want like gmail app if its a `mailto:` link

here is the methode.

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
{
   if(url.contains("tel:")) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
   } else {
        progressBar.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
   }
}
```